# does thread.sleep release the lock of synchronized?

Tags: java, multithreading

i have this code and i cant understand why main thread doesn't print false after 1sec ???

```
public abstract class Callable<E> implements Runnable {

    private E val=null;
    protected abstract E call();
    public synchronized boolean isReady()
    {
       if(val!=null)
           return true;
       return false;
    }
    public synchronized E waitForValue() throws InterruptedException
    {
        while(!isReady())
        {
            wait();
        }
        return val;
    }
    public synchronized void run()
    {
        E temp = call();
            val = temp;
            notifyAll();
        
    }


public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException
{
    Callable<String> c = new Callable<String>() {
        protected String call() {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(5000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }
            return "AAA";
        }};
    new Thread(c).start();
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    System.out.println(c.isReady());
    System.out.println(c.waitForValue());
    System.out.println(c.isReady());

}
}
```

if i change synchronized of method run like that it works

```
@Override
    public void run() {
        E temp = call();
        synchronized (this) {
            val = temp;
            isReady = true;
            notifyAll();
        }
    }
```

if thread sleep it doesn't release the lock of the object ?
and about wait it release the lock right ?

in the last i should print
false     //after 1sec
AAA       //after 4sec
true

Comment: Yes/No question answerable by single google search.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation can answer questions like this, and usually does.

[Thread.sleep()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#sleep(long)) does not release the monitor (or 'lock').

[Object.wait()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#wait--) does release the monitor.